# GUI editor for DOT language (Mac OS)

Tags: user-interface, editor, uml, graphviz, dot

i have a problem. I need to create pure diagram for my project (Django).
I use django-extensions to generate DOT diagram. Diagram is very pure, but now i want to add for example comments on this diagram.
It is possible to do this?
Maybe anyone can advise me some software for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [OS X version of graphviz](http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/), though I haven't used it in years so can't vouch whether it can annotate diagrams.

Comment: Not supported anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DiagramCreator (http://blog.chipp.com/diagramcreator-in-beta-get-yours-now/) in beta for Mac or give a chance to Leonhard (http://algorithmique.net/leonhard.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Graph Galaxy](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/graph-galaxy/id1473722262?mt=12) is a graph editor encourages an approach to editing graphs in WYSIWYG fashion. It provides an out-of-the-box environment to edit graphs, and supports to sketch graphs on canvas without thinking the DOT source code.